# How to create and manipulate powerpoint tables using openXML in C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

i am looking [at this example on how to manipulate powerpoint templates from C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2008/11/18/creating-a-presentation-report-based-on-data.aspx) and the one thing missing is the ability to manipulate rows in a table.  Does anyone have any examples of looping through some set of records and adding rows to a powerpoint table

In particular:

- Adding and removing rows
- Word wrap / auto adjusting heights given text length
- Updating text in cells
- Dealing with if the number of records would cause the table to span multiple powerpoint slides

Comment: #1 and #3 are able to be handled by OpenXML. #2 and #4 are not as they require a rendering application (e.g. PowerPoint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, i wound up purchasing aspose.slides which is great and well worth the cost when trying to auto generate powerpoin files.